# How to remove error message from error class in on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 fields in my form. Name, age, from and to. Name and age belong to error class(errror1) and from and to belong to error class(error2).

```
  .error1 {
      color: red;
  }
  .error2 {
      color: green;
  }
```

JS

```
 jQuery( function ($) {
     var classes = {
        'Name': 'error1',
        'Age': 'error1',
        'from': 'error2',
        'to': 'error2'
     }

     $('#form1').validate({
        rules: {
           'Name': {
               required: true
           },
           'Age': {
               required: true
           },
           'from': {
               required: true
           },
           'to': {
               required: true
           }
        },
        messages: {
          'Name': {
              required: 'Name is required!'
          },
          'Age': {
              required: 'Age is required!'
          },
          'from': {
              required: 'from is required!'
          },
          'to': {
             required: 'to is required!'
          }
       },
       errorPlacement: function ( err, element ) {
          err.addClass( classes[element.attr('name')] )
          err.insertBefore( element );
       },
       submitHandler: function ( form ) {
          form.submit();
       }
    });
});

$("#name1").click(function() {
    $("label.error2").hide();
    $(".error2").removeClass("error");
});
```

HTML

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <input name="Name" id="name1" />:name
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="Age" id="age1" />:age
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="from" id="from1" />:from
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="to" id="to1"/>:to
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

My requirement is when I **click on name** field the error message in **from** field only should disappear. Now both from and to field messages disappear. How can I implement that??

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3uchB/)

Comment: That's bcoz your using `class`. Use `id` instead.

Comment: Post your html code.Then we can manipulate it through jquery based on your DOM structure..

Comment: <form id="form1" method="post" action="">
    <div>
        <input name="Name" id="name1" />:name
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="Age" id="age1" />:age
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="from" id="from1" />:from
    </div>
        <div>
        <input name="to" id="to1"/>:to
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

Comment: included jsfiddle too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5RrGa/698/).

From what I understand you want to hide the validation on another field. You may get that field by its id and find the error lable which is a sibling.

```
$("#name1").click(function() {
 $("#from1").siblings('.error').hide();
});
```

If you would like a more generic solution you may use data attributes.

Here is an example:

Add a descriptive data attribute to the input field you want to do the action from

```
<input name="Name" id="name1" data-hide-error-on="#from1"/>:name
```

Then your js can look like this:

```
$('input[data-hide-error-on]').click(function() {
    var inputToHide = $(this).data('hide-error-on');
     $(inputToHide).siblings('.error').remove();
});
```

Also I would suggest classes for you error label styling on the parent div. As you would lose the styling on the second submit when doing it your way.

```
<div class="green-errors">
    <input name="Name" id="name1" data-hide-error-on="#from1"/>:name
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.green-errors label.error {
    color: green;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5RrGa/702/).

Comment: The generic data attribute solution has the added benefit of being able to unobtrusively define more than one target to be hidden. Just pass in a valid selector. You could easily hide both from and to errors by changing the data attribute to data-hide-error-on="#from1,#to1"

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code:

```
$("#name1").click(function() {
 $("#form1").find($(".error2")).eq(0).hide();
 $(".error2").removeClass("error");
});
```